# Kubernetes is crashing with repeated "CrashLoopBackOff" on kube-systems

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set up Kubernetes on a VM with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. I selected the Docker for container runtime, and before installing any CNI. Disk and memory usage remains sufficient.

The Kubernetes is crashing with repeated "CrashLoopBackOff" on kube-systems. What breaks are the kube-controller, kube-proxy and kube-scheduler.

Below is what I keep getting:

```
root@master:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-t44fz                     0/1     Pending            0               12m
kube-system   coredns-5d78c9869d-vzbq2                     0/1     Pending            0               12m
kube-system   etcd-master.example.com                      1/1     Running            4 (5m53s ago)   12m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master.example.com            1/1     Running            6 (5m10s ago)   13m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master.example.com   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (100s ago)    11m
kube-system   kube-proxy-ltwtp                             0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (104s ago)    12m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master.example.com            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (92s ago)     12m
```

I caught one of the problematic pods and looked through the logs, but found no clues:

```
root@master:~# kubectl logs kube-proxy-ltwtp -n kube-system
I0417 15:20:58.122219       1 node.go:141] Successfully retrieved node IP: 10.0.2.15
I0417 15:20:58.122427       1 server_others.go:110] "Detected node IP" address="10.0.2.15"
I0417 15:20:58.122498       1 server_others.go:551] "Using iptables proxy"
I0417 15:20:58.144359       1 server_others.go:190] "Using iptables Proxier"
I0417 15:20:58.144423       1 server_others.go:197] "kube-proxy running in dual-stack mode" ipFamily=IPv4
I0417 15:20:58.144430       1 server_others.go:198] "Creating dualStackProxier for iptables"
I0417 15:20:58.144435       1 server_others.go:465] "Detect-local-mode set to ClusterCIDR, but no cluster CIDR defined"
I0417 15:20:58.144438       1 server_others.go:521] "Defaulting to no-op detect-local" detectLocalMode="ClusterCIDR"
I0417 15:20:58.144467       1 proxier.go:253] "Setting route_localnet=1 to allow node-ports on localhost; to change this either disable iptables.localhostNodePorts (--iptables-localhost-nodeports) or set nodePortAddresses (--nodeport-addresses) to filter loopback addresses"
I0417 15:20:58.145393       1 server.go:657] "Version info" version="v1.27.1"
I0417 15:20:58.145691       1 server.go:659] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
I0417 15:20:58.148938       1 conntrack.go:52] "Setting nf_conntrack_max" nfConntrackMax=131072
I0417 15:20:58.151422       1 config.go:188] "Starting service config controller"
I0417 15:20:58.152780       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
I0417 15:20:58.152154       1 config.go:97] "Starting endpoint slice config controller"
I0417 15:20:58.152838       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config
I0417 15:20:58.152581       1 config.go:315] "Starting node config controller"
I0417 15:20:58.152843       1 shared_informer.go:311] Waiting for caches to sync for node config
I0417 15:20:58.253957       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for node config
I0417 15:20:58.254322       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for service config
I0417 15:20:58.254380       1 shared_informer.go:318] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config
```

After some time, even the commands are no longer executed and the following message is printed:

```
root@master:~# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
The connection to the server 10.0.2.15:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

root@master:~# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 10.0.2.15:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

After a reboot or a little more time, the command can be executed again. However, the crash still persists, and the problem repeats itself. Can I get some help to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you followed this procedure? https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/; I don't see any Network Plugins from the shared code.

Comment: could you share more details about the pods in crashloop? e.g., using `kubectl get pod -n kube-system   kube-proxy-ltwtp -oyaml`